# go test and go run execute the following channel code, but the results are different. why?

Tags: go

```
main.go

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    ch := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    <-ch
}
```

```
main_test.go

func Test_Main(t *testing.T) {
    main()
}
```

go run main.go

```
  hello
  fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
  goroutine 1 [chan receive]:
  main.main()
```

but
go test -v main_test.go -run=Test_Main

```
=== RUN   Test_Main
hello
```

go test will not report an error and will always run.
After consulting a lot of information, I didn't find an answer to explain this phenomenon. Maybe my way is wrong?This channel method is used in projects.
Thanks.

Comment: Test_Main has its own  goroutine running, thus no deadlock.

Comment: And your test doesn't report an error because it never completes. To get an error, it would have to panic or signal error e.g. with `T.Error()`.

Comment: why does go test not complete. This is the problem? how to catch this error. Itself does not return @icza

Comment: So how does go run code achieve the same effect as go test?@Volker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a regular program, it waits for input from channel. And because there is only one goroutine there is no way to receive the input from channel (no other thread to send to it). Thus deadlock is reported.

On the other hand test runner uses goroutines to execute tests. So there is more then one goroutine spawned and the deadlock is not detected (runtime assumes that other goroutine could send to channel).

To answer your question from comment: go run and go test are not supposed to achieve the same effects. go run executes your program, go test executes procedures that test your code. These commands executes two different programs.

I am not sure if you can detect this kind of errors (deadlocks) with tests.

**Edit:**
`go test` waits for test to finish (you can configure how long with `-timeout d` option). So I assume it spawns goroutine that waits for `timer.Timer` to expire, so there is no deadlock (there is always one goroutine that has a chance to be executed).

**Edit2:**
Try this program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    go func() {
        t := time.NewTimer(10 * time.Second)
        <-t.C
    }()
    fmt.Println("hello")
    ch := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    <-ch
}
```

It waits 10 seconds before reporting deadlock.

**Edit3:**
Or take a look at flowing code that illustrates how test runner works:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func original_main_func() {
    fmt.Println("hello")
    ch := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    <-ch
}

func test() {
    original_main_func()
}

func test_runner() {
    ch := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    go func() {
        test()
        close(ch)
    }()
    t := time.NewTimer(10 * time.Second)
    select {
    case <-t.C:
        panic("timeout")
    case <-ch:
        fmt.Println("test executed")
    }
}

func main() {
    test_runner()
}
```

Comment: I understand the principle of deadlock. But go test has no extra code, why would I add a goroutine to ensure the code execution? If go test also reports an error, then I will not ask.

As long as there is enough goroutine in main, will it not report an error in the end?
If the execution of goroutine in main is complete, will it report an error?

Comment: To add onto this, after 10 minutes of hanging the test will time out and panic with an explanation of where it is hanging in terms of goroutines.

Comment: If execute go test with the same principle as edit3, I can understand.